# Two ways to throw exception in C++ (without using the heap)

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I have made my own `MatrixArithmeticException` whose constructor takes an `int` that specifies which type of mistake was made. I have tried in my code two ways to throw the exception. These are the two ways:

1. Create an instance of `MatrixArithmeticException` and throw the instance.
2. `throw MatrixArithmeticException(0); //or whatever the int is supposed to be`

The code works either way, but my question is, is either way more efficient (in terms of space )? Also, why does the second way seem to work just as well?

EDIT: From a couple of answers I have received on this question (and a comment on one of those answers), I should have provided my code for the first way.

I never used dynamic memory in either way (I was trying to hint that with the title of the question, but this is clearly not enough). As for my code for the first method, I did this:

```
MatrixArithmeticException dimensionsDoNotMatch(0);
throw dimensionsDoNotMatch;
```

I guess this question would be the stack-based C++ equivalent of asking someone the difference between this:

```
MatrixAritmeticException dimensionsDoNotMatch = new MatrixArithmeticException(0);
throw dimensionsDoNotMatch;
```

and this:

```
throw new MatrixArithmeticException(0);
```

Both questions seem to share a common answer. `std::cout << "Thanks, guys!!" << std::endl;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way is explicitly creating a local object as an lvalue (something you can take the address of) and then throwing it.

The second way is creating a temporary object (an rvalue) and throws it - however, throwing usually involves copying - should it not be either elided or moved.

The second one is potentially more efficient because it can elide and / or move without your intervention or hints.

Also, a small "note" - using int to symbolize what mistake has been made is something you may wish to refrain from doing even though I can't see what is it that you're exactly doing; try an enum instead!

Comment: The OP doesn't even show, what he's using for the _'1st way'_ declaration.

Comment: @g-makulik Looks like I inferred what he was on about correctly! :)

Comment: Although one question about the whole enum thing: do enumerations need their own files (especially since you are suggesting using those as constructor parameters instead of an `int`)?

Comment: @Mike Warren no, enums are basically type definitions just like classes, hell, there is even "enum class" since cpp11 which basically disables all int conversions

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't construct exceptions on the heap (using `new()`).
2. Don't copy caught exception instances, re-throw.
3. Catch them using `const` references.

These are my rules of thumb for dealing with C++ exceptions.

> why does the second way seem to work just as well?

Your `MatrixArithmeticException` simply provides a constructor taking an `int argument`. There's no difference with allocation of them (from the constructor declarations) and both methods will create the exception on the stack (besides you had in mind to use `new MatrixArithmeticException ()` when saying *'Create an instance'*, see my point 1. then).

Answer (score 0):

You can throw pretty much anything in C++, though we usually throw errors.

Having decided to throw an error, you can throw an error object directly, or throw a pointer to it, tho most code have seen throws the error object directly.

Having decided to throw it directly you can construct it within the throw statement, or in advance. I recommend construction it in place if its a simple error, as appears the case above

You line lines are basically equivalent, except that in the first, the temporary error value is logically being dumped in a local variable before being throw, while in the later it resides in a un-named temporary variable. Its unlike they will differ in speed, but if they do, the later will likely be the faster one.